# How to implement input into multiplication table?

Tags: python, input

Heyy, i got a bit of help earlier but am stuck once again :(
I am completely new to coding so i apologize for questions on such simple matters.
I am writing a program that puts out a multiplication table for the numbers that the user chooses(Using while instead of for to better understand how while loops work)
This is what i have so far:

```
print(end='')
max_x = int(input("Number of columns:"))
x = 1
while x <= max_x:
     print(end='')
     x += 1
max_y = int(input("Number of rows:"))
y = 1
while y <= max_y:
     print('')
     print(end='')
     z = 1
     while z <= max_x:
          print(y*z, end='\t')
          z += 1
     y += 1
```

And this is the output that i get:

```
Number of columns:5
Number of rows:4

1   2   3   4   5   
2   4   6   8   10  
3   6   9   12  15  
4   8   12  16  20
```

My issue is that i can´t for the life of me figure out how to get the table to also include the 1, as in:

```
    1   2   3   4       
1   1   2   3   4   
2   2   4   6   8       
3   3   6   9   12  
4   4   8   12  16
```

Appreciate any help as i´ve been trying and googling a bunch and frankly feel quite dumb struggling with such a simple thing

Answer (score 0):

The extra digits are for the axis labels so they need to be drawn separately.

Try this code:

```
print(end='')
max_x = int(input("Number of columns:"))
x = 1
while x <= max_x:
     print(end='')
     x += 1
max_y = int(input("Number of rows:"))
y = 1
print(' \t' + '\t'.join([str(i+1) for i in range(max_x)]), end="") # labels X axis
while y <= max_y:
     print('')
     print(end='')
     z = 1
     print(y,end='\t')  # label Y axis
     while z <= max_x:              
          print(y*z, end='\t')
          z += 1
     y += 1
```

Output:

```
Number of columns:4
Number of rows:4

        1       2       3       4
1       1       2       3       4
2       2       4       6       8
3       3       6       9       12
4       4       8       12      16
```

Comment: Don't use `if z==1:`, just put that code before the `while` loop.

Comment: Good catch. Thanks.